# Using setInterval to replace text via textContent

Tags: javascript

I'm new to js and I can't quite get this [small loop](https://codepen.io/stordahl_/pen/wvadeoa) to work.

```
// array to store strings
var poem = [
  "string 1",
  "string 2",
  "string 3",
  "string 4",
  "string 5",
];
// text animation loop
var animInterval = window.setInterval(
  function(){
    for(i = 0; i === poem.length; i++){
      document.querySelector("#text").textContent = poem[i];
    }
  }, 1000 /*1000ms = 1sec*/
);
```

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious!

Comment: `i < poem.length` not `===`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the `for` loop *(the `setInterval` is already looping)*:

```js
// array to store strings
var poem = [
  "string 1",
  "string 2",
  "string 3",
  "string 4",
  "string 5",
];
var i = 1; // Start at 1 because 0 is already displayed

var animInterval = window.setInterval(function() {
    document.querySelector("#text").textContent = poem[i];
    i = ++i % poem.length; // Add 1 until it reaches 5, then back to 0, 1, 2...
}, 1000);
```

```html
<h1 id="text">string 1</h1>
```

https://codepen.io/blex41/pen/poJPwKr

**Note:** if `i = ++i % poem.length;` is unclear, you can rewrite it as:

```
i++;
if (i >= poem.length) { i = 0; }
```

**Bonus**

With the code above, the animation starts after 1 second. That means you need to set the first value directly into the HTML, otherwise, it's going to be empty for the first second. If you don't want to have to do this, you can use the trick below:

```js
var poem = ["string 1", "string 2", "string 3", "string 4", "string 5"],
    i = 0; // Start at 0

// This is an IIFE (Immediatly Invoked Function Expression)
// As its name suggests, it executes immediately
(function loop() {
    document.querySelector("#text").textContent = poem[i];
    i = ++i % poem.length;
    setTimeout(loop, 1000);
})();
```

```html
<h1 id="text"></h1>
```

https://codepen.io/blex41/pen/GRJmEwJ